# Graph did not generate everytime and have extra legends

Tags: excel, vba

[image]

For the above pic, this is the graph that i gotten after i run my code. The graph does not generate all the time and have 2 legends as shown below. [image]

The picture with the graph is the outcome that i wanted. As you can see the format of the plot differs too.

```
Sub plottinggraph()

    Dim LastRowOfA As Long, LastRowOfB As Long
    Dim ColumnARngData As Range, ColumnBRngData As Range
    Dim maxscaleforX As Long, maxscaleforY As Long
    Dim xAxes As Axis, yAxes As Axis

    LastRowOfA = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    LastRowOfB = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
    Set ColumnARngData = ActiveSheet.Range("A4:A" & LastRowOfA)
    Set ColumnBRngData = ActiveSheet.Range("B4:B" & LastRowOfB)
    maxscaleforX = ActiveSheet.Cells(LastRowOfA, 1).Value
    maxscaleforY = ActiveSheet.Cells(LastRowOfB, 2).Value
        
    Dim cht As Shape
    Set cht = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart
    With cht.Chart                    
        .HasTitle = True
        .ChartTitle.Text = "Power VS Time"
        .SetSourceData Source:=Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:B" & LastRowOfB)
        .ChartType = xlXYScatterLinesNoMarkers
       
        Set xAxes = .Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary)
        With xAxes
            .HasTitle = True
            .AxisTitle.Text = "TIME (Minutes)"
            .MinimumScale = 0
            .MaximumScale = maxscaleforX

        End With
        
        Set yAxes = .Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary)
        With yAxes
            .HasTitle = True
            .AxisTitle.Text = "POWER (mW)"
            .MinimumScaleIsAuto = True
            .MaximumScaleIsAuto = True
        End With
    End With
           
End Sub
```

Comment: Your code should work. Anyhow, you must have a "Sheet 1" sheet (not "Sheet1"), the `LastRowOfB` should be previously calculated. Is what you show us all the code you are testing?

Comment: Ya, my mistake, i didnt run the LastRowOfB function. Thats why it didnt work. I got another question. I only hv 2 columns in the database thus thats why i set them as SetSourceData range. My code could run but it didnt generate a graph. Why is it so?

Comment: Do you have any data in columns A:B?

Comment: Ya, i have data for my columns. I have updated my question